# How do I access a preprocessor macro from code in Xcode using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macros, build-settings

How do I access a preprocessor macro in Xcode from Swift code for a string I've defined? Other stack**overflow** posts show how to create the macros, but do not show me how to access them in code sufficiently.

For example, I have defined a constant called HELLO_WORLD_STRING = "Hello World!" in Preprocessor Macros Not Used in Precompiled Headers in the build settings as in the image:

[image: Preprocessor Macros Not Used in Precompiled Headers]

How would I print that constant in the debug window, just as an example?

I actually need to use the value of the app name to set the title of a navigation bar, but I would like to take this route in order to do that.

I have tried using #if ... #endif statements, but the constant was not recognized.

Comment: What language are you using? Swift eschews the use of macros. #ifdef work, but defines, not so much.

Comment: I'm using Swift.

Comment: And I have to ask: what benefit do you think you'd get by retrieving this value from the build system, rather than setting it for your self in your application delegate, say?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not possible in Swift. You can get the full path of the executable with Bundle.main.executablePath.

Comment: Just for convenience. Just in case I change the app name in settings and forget to set it in code.

Comment: I used to take the value from Bundle.main like you describe, but then I would have to use string manipulations. I'm just looking for a simpler and better way to do what I have already been doing, just for the sake of doing something more perfect than before.

Comment: Plus the knowledge I gain will come in useful in the future for when I use preprocessor macros.

Comment: It's nice to learn something new to keep life interesting.

Comment: Yeah, so Swift is valiantly trying to kill off the use of macros, as they can make code hard to reason about, being one more place one needs to look for constants.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use syntax like:

```
 #if DEBUG_API_CALL
    print("Start loading \(method) \(url)")
 #endif
```

You have to add DEBUG_API_CALL (or other your name) to Active Compilation Conditions in the build settings tab:

[image: Active Compilation Conditions in the build settings tab]