# Swift conditional statement for separating UITest code

Tags: swift, uitest

```
IF UItest is running 
{
//execute this code
}
else
{
//execute this code

}
```

can anyone tell what should be the conditional statement here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access a preprocessor macro from code in Xcode using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646397/how-do-i-access-a-preprocessor-macro-from-code-in-xcode-using-swift)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: pass args through test code**

```
// In UI test file
class ProfileUI: XCTestCase {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        app.launchArguments = ["-isUITestMode", "user_324234"]
        app.launch()
    }
}
```

**Method 2: pass args through scheme**

[image]

**Check the args**

```
if CommandLine.arguments.contains("-isUITestMode") {
    // running ui test
} else if CommandLine.arguments.contains("-isUnitTestMode") {
    // running unit tests
} else {
    // normal
}
```